# Is it possible to use SIM900 GPIO to control relays without using external MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, gsm, sim900

From the product manual / reference guide it looks like SIM900 / SIM900A is already equipped with 12 GPIOs.

But could not find information on how to use these GPIOs to control *relays* directly, instead of routing them through additional MCUs.

Most examples on the net (such as [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Home-automation-system-using-Arduino-and-SIM900-GS/%20this)) use the SIM900 just for read/write, completely ignoring its GPIO capabilities.

Any pointers on how to use the GPIOs of SIM900 as control signals directly - please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a sidenote: Quectel has modems which allow this https://www.quectel.com/Qdownload/M66_OpenCPU_SDK.html the M66 should be priced similarly to the SIM900

Answer (score 5):

The GPIOs in sim900 module is meant to be controlled by AT commands through serial port ofcourse.

if u see the AT command manual of sim900 you will find the following at command to control the GPIOs

```
AT+SGPIO=<operation>,<GPIO>,<Function>,<level>
```

following is the Description to the above function!

[image]

P.S. i know this question is about 20days old and he might have already got the answer.I'm only sharing because it may help other.!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will need to blow away the included AT-command virtual machine and write your own firmware layer, to be loaded in the SIM900 flash.

Comment: Thank you. Know any examples or tutorials anywhere on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Refer "[SIM900_Customer Application Building Tutorial_Application Note_V1.00.pdf](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_Customer%20Application%20Building%20Tutorial_Application%20Note_V1.00.pdf)"

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Usually very short answers that simply provide a link to resources are discouraged. In the future (when you have enough reputation), a post like this may be better served as a comment.

Comment: Hi, I don't have enough reputation to add comment,hence added answer

Comment: No problem! Just a tip for the future. Again, welcome.

Comment: Thanks Daniel,Why I am not getting "add answer" option to this question?(https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340637/how-do-you-independently-program-a-gsm-gprs-ic)

Comment: It has been marked as a duplicate question, and cannot be answered.